# What is the call when a runner misses 2nd base on a 1st to 3rd and a dead ball call?

Tags: rules, baseball, officiating

runner on 1st. ball is hit to outfield. runner advances to 3rd missing 2nd base. the throw coming in to 3rd base goes into dugout. What is the proper call?

Answer (score 1):

The runner would be awarded home plate on the overthrow, however, the runner would be out on appeal (if the fielding team appeals) for missing second base. The runner could return and touch second base on the dead ball before touching 3rd and home, in order. But once the runner touches 3rd base, if they missed 2nd then they would be out on appeal. If the fielding team does not appeal, then the runner would score a run. Here are the relevant MLB rules:

> Rule 5.09(c)(1) Comment (Rule 7.10(a) Comment): “Retouch,” in this rule, means to tag up and start from a contact with the base after the ball is caught. A base.
>
> (2)  With the ball in play, while advancing or returning to a base, he fails to touch each base in order before he, or a missed base, is tagged;
>
> APPROVED RULING: (A) No runner may return to touch a missed base after a following runner has scored. (B) When the ball is dead, no runner may return to touch a missed base or one he has left after he has advanced to and touched a base beyond the missed base.
>
> Rule 5.09(c)(2) Comment (Rule 7.10(b) Comment):
>
> PLAY—(A) Batter hits ball out of park or ground rule double and misses first base (ball is dead)—he may return to first base to correct his mistake before he touches second but if he touches second he may not return to first and if defensive team appeals he is declared out at first.
>
> PLAY—(B) Batter hits ball to shortstop who throws wild into stand (ball is dead)—batter-runner misses first base but is awarded second base on the overthrow. Even though the umpire has awarded the runner second base on the overthrow, the runner must touch first base before he proceeds to second base.
>
> These are appeal plays.

Answer (score 0):

What would happen is each player offensive player would get 2 bases from where they were at the start of the play. ie: The batter would advance to second base.

According to SportsRec.com and the official MLB rulebook,

> If the ball gets by the first baseman and skips out of play, the umpire will place the batter at second base. The rule is that when the defensive team puts the ball out of play, the batter will get two bases from the base he was at when the play started. Because the batter started the play at home, two bases would put him at second base. It doesn't matter that he was just a few feet from the base when it went out of play. He is entitled to second base and that's it.

This is proof that inside the dugout is out of play from baseballrulesacademy.com, verified with the official MLB rulebook.

> The lip of the dugout is considered in play but the steps going down to the dugout and the floor of the dugout is dead ball area. If the fielder does not have both feet on the playing field at the time of the catch, it is not a catch.

Therefore, both of these concepts apply, and since the dugout is out of bounds, both of the runners would advance 2 bases. It would not matter that he did not touch second base, he would advance to third base, but if he had touched 2nd base before the ball was thrown out of play, then he would be awarded 2 bases, he would go to home base.